# check type of listView item

Tags: android, listview

I has create joblog as a listView and in each row of item in listView can be
text or image. 
I need to check there is image or text to specify click event.

```
 jobLogListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int position, final long id) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), jobLogListView);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_joblog_share, popup.getMenu());
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    JobLog jobLogItem = (JobLog) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.copy_text:
                                copyToClipBoard();
                                break;
                            case R.id.share_text:
                                shareToOtherApp();
                                break;

                            default:
                                break;

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice trick to capture the onClick event, for any arbitary View within a ListView - so you you know which particular view was clicked, e.g a TextView or ImageView. Although it requires extending the BaseAdapter class.

If you extend `BaseAdapter`, a simple override (without view recycling) would be as follows:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent{
  if (convertView==null)  convertView=mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mylistitem, null)
  //first, create an onclick listener that we can later access from our Activity:
  View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
      ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
      }
    }
  //then, assign the onClick Listener to all our Views within the ListView...
  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mytextview).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
  (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myimageview).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
  //repeat for every View you want to capture clicks for...
}
```

Then in your `Activity`, you can access the onClick for each item of your list view, so you can change you action depending which View the user clicked:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapaterView.OnItemClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, longid){
    if (View.getId()==R.id.mytextview) {
      //do stuff if textview was clicked 
    } else if (View.getId()==R.id.myimageview) {
      //do stuff if imageview was clicked
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: if I draw view programmatic and view will draw when item has append to the list. how can I use this method

Comment: Can you post sample code?  Will be difficult to paste here, perhaps best as a new question.

Answer (score -2):

You may find this link helpful along with the answer at the top of this page-

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

Code Snippet:

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;
             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
             holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
         holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
         rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
             if (v.getId() == R.id.image){
               // do something.
             } else if (v.getId() == R.id.textView){
               // do something else.
             }

        }
    });   
    return rowView;
```